# Devexpress Reporting: How to Control Parameter Field's Width?

Tags: asp.net, devexpress, xtrareport

I'm using Xtrareports for reporting.

There is a paragraph that a part of it is coming from a parameter.

Let's say "Dear [USERNAME] welcome"

You see, I wasn't be able to put [USERNAME] into a paragraph. So I did it like:
"Dear" [USERNAME] "welcome".

But now, if the username is short like "ab", it looks like:
"Dear ab_***_*__** welcome".

If it's longer like "qwertyasdfghjkzxcvbnm", it looks like:
"Dear qwertyasdfgwelcome".

How can I do this in a XtraReport file? Like a label control in Asp.net: "Hello" + USERNAME.ToString() + "welcome";

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Drop an XRLabel onto a Detail band of the [databound XtraReport](http://help.devexpress.com/XtraReports/CustomDocument2598.aspx) and set the label's Text as follows:

```
        this.xrLabel1.Text = "Dear [USERNAME] welcome";
```

In this case, everything should work properly.  Note, in this example the USERNAME is a fieldname in the underlying DataSource.

Comment: Thank you, I did it this way though(on Report.cs):
private void Detail_BeforePrint(object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintEventArgs e)
        {
            xrFullNameLable.Text = Parameters["NAME"].Value + @" " + Parameters["SURNAME"].Value;
 }